# Ajax Start Event Firing after return from Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to show a `ProgressBar` when my page is doing an `ajax` request.

I am creating a `dialog` dynamically with an `image` inside it and I would like to show it on the `ajaxStart` event. The problem is that when I make a `ajax` call then `ajax` start fires after the return from `controller`.

```
$(document).on('ajaxStart',function(){
    alert('x');
    $.OpenLoading(); //method which is creating the dialog and image
});
```

In this case the `alert` is called immediately.
But there is not dialog created

But if write the same code like this

```
$(document).on('ajaxStart',function(){
    console.log('x');
    $.OpenLoading(); //method which is creating the dialog and image
});
```

Then in console `x` is printed after returning from `controller` action and still the dialog is not created. If I just run the `$.OpenLoading()` in console then it works fine as expected.

Please let me know where I am doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alert() stops all interaction with the browser until the message is dismissed , that is you press ok button.
while console.log() just prints the message to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your javascript to something like this:

```js
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    console.log('x');
    $.OpenLoading(); //method which is creating the dialog and image
});
```

.ajaxStart is just a short form for .on("ajaxStart" though I find it works better in certain situations.